# Oracle SELECT query: collapsing NULL values when pairing up dates for different fields

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, pivot-table, analytic-functions

This question is very much like [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877113/oracle-select-query-collapsing-null-values-when-pairing-up-dates), but a bit more complicated.  [Rob van Wijk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877113/oracle-select-query-collapsing-null-values-when-pairing-up-dates/2877502#2877502) worked perfectly for my other question, and I've been using that as a starting point.  My problem now is that I am pivoting dates for different fields.  Whereas before I cared about getting all `open_in` and `open_out` values for a given `id`, now I want `new_in`, `new_out`, `open_in`, `open_out`, `fixed_in`, and `fixed_out` for each `id`.  I have the following:

```
SELECT id,
       state,
       state_time,
       MAX(new_row_num) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY state_time) AS new_row_group,
       MAX(open_row_num) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY state_time) AS open_row_group,
       MAX(fixed_row_num) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY state_time) AS fixed_row_group
FROM (
       SELECT id,
              state,
              state_time,
              CASE state
                   WHEN 'New'
                   THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY state_time)
              END AS new_row_num,
              CASE state
                   WHEN 'Open'
                   THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY state_time)
              END AS open_row_num,
              CASE state
                   WHEN 'Fixed'
                   THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY state_time)
              END AS fixed_row_num
       FROM ...
     )
```

This gives me data like the following:

```
id  state   state_time           new_row_group  open_row_group  fixed_row_group
1   New     2009-03-03 00:03:31  1
1   Closed  2009-03-04 04:15:27  1
2   New     2010-05-22 14:38:49  1
2   Open    2010-05-22 14:39:14  1              2
2   Fixed   2010-05-22 17:15:27  1              2               3
```

I would like data like the following:

```
id  new_in               new_out              open_in              open_out             fixed_in             fixed_out
1   2009-03-03 00:03:31  2009-03-04 04:15:27
2   2010-05-22 14:38:49  2010-05-22 14:39:14  2010-05-22 14:39:14  2010-05-22 17:15:27  2010-05-22 17:15:27
```

How can I pivot the data to get this date-pairing for each `id`?

**Edit:**  to clarify, an `id` can enter and leave a state multiple times.  For example, an `id` might go from New to Open to Fixed to Open to Fixed to Closed.  In that case, there would need to be as many rows as is necessary to hold all the state times, e.g.:

```
id  new_in               new_out              open_in              open_out             fixed_in             fixed_out
4   2009-01-01 00:00:00  2009-01-02 00:00:00  2009-01-02 00:00:00  2009-01-03 00:00:00  2009-01-03 00:00:00  2009-01-04 00:00:00
4                                             2009-01-04 00:00:00  2009-01-05 00:00:00  2009-01-05 00:00:00  2009-01-06 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sarah,

Here is an example with your sample data:

```
SQL> create table yourtable (id,state,state_time)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 'New', to_date('2009-03-03 00:03:31','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  4  select 1, 'Closed', to_date('2009-03-04 04:15:27','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  5  select 2, 'New', to_date('2010-05-22 14:38:49','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  6  select 2, 'Open', to_date('2010-05-22 14:39:14','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  7  select 2, 'Fixed', to_date('2010-05-22 17:15:27','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  8  select 3, 'New', date '2009-01-01' from dual union all
  9  select 3, 'Open', date '2009-01-02' from dual union all
 10  select 3, 'Fixed', date '2009-01-03' from dual union all
 11  select 3, 'Open', date '2009-01-04' from dual union all
 12  select 3, 'Fixed', date '2009-01-05' from dual union all
 13  select 3, 'Closed', date '2009-01-06' from dual
 14  /

Table created.
```

The query:

```
SQL> select id
  2       , max(decode(state,'New',state_time))   new_in
  3       , max(decode(state,'New',out_time))     new_out
  4       , max(decode(state,'Open',state_time))  open_in
  5       , max(decode(state,'Open',out_time))    open_out
  6       , max(decode(state,'Fixed',state_time)) fixed_in
  7       , max(decode(state,'Fixed',out_time))   fixed_out
  8    from ( select id
  9                , state
 10                , state_time
 11                , max(cnt) over (partition by id order by state_time) the_row
 12                , lead(state_time) over (partition by id order by state_time) out_time
 13             from ( select id
 14                         , state
 15                         , state_time
 16                         , count(*) over (partition by id,state order by state_time) cnt
 17                      from yourtable
 18                  )
 19         )
 20   group by id
 21       , the_row
 22   order by id
 23       , the_row
 24  /

        ID NEW_IN              NEW_OUT             OPEN_IN             OPEN_OUT            FIXED_IN            FIXED_OUT
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 03-03-2009 00:03:31 04-03-2009 04:15:27
         2 22-05-2010 14:38:49 22-05-2010 14:39:14 22-05-2010 14:39:14 22-05-2010 17:15:27 22-05-2010 17:15:27
         3 01-01-2009 00:00:00 02-01-2009 00:00:00 02-01-2009 00:00:00 03-01-2009 00:00:00 03-01-2009 00:00:00 04-01-2009 00:00:00
         3                                         04-01-2009 00:00:00 05-01-2009 00:00:00 05-01-2009 00:00:00 06-01-2009 00:00:00

4 rows selected.
```

To understand how it works, execute the query from the inside out and check the intermediate result sets. Please let me know if you need some additional explanation.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Yay!  This works great.  I was hoping you'd notice this question since you answered my last Oracle question so well.  :)  Thanks!  I did have to add an extra `SELECT` outside of yours, so I could have a `WHERE new_in IS NOT NULL OR open_in IS NOT NULL OR fixed_in IS NOT NULL`, since I was getting a lot of empty rows.

Comment: For the various `max(decode(state,'New',state_time))` statements, I think `min` should be used.  I had some trouble where different states were skipped when using `max`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select news.id, news.state_time as new_in, min(not_news.state_time) as new_out
   , min(opens.state_time) as open_in
   , min(not_opens.state_time) as open_out
   , min(closes.state_time) as close_in
   , min(not_closed.state_time) as close_out
from
   (SELECT id,
          state,
          state_time
      from mytable
      where state = 'New' ) news
   left join
   (SELECT id,
          state,
          state_time
      from mytable
      where state <> 'New' ) not_news     on news.id = not_news.id and news.state_time <= not_news.state_time
   left join
   (SELECT id,
          state,
          state_time
      from mytable
      where state = 'Open' ) opens     on news.id = opens.id and news.state_time <= opens.state_time
   left join
   (SELECT id,
          state,
          state_time
      from mytable
      where state not in ('New', 'Open' )) not_opens     on news.id = opens.id and news.state_time <= opens.state_time    and opens.state_time <= not_opens.state_time
   left join
   (SELECT id,
          state,
          state_time
      from mytable
      where state = 'Closed' ) closes     on news.id = closes.id and news.state_time <= closes.state_time
   left join
   (SELECT id,
          state,
          state_time
      from mytable
      where state not in ('Closed' )) not_closed     on news.id = not_closed.id and news.state_time <= closes.state_time    and closes.state_time <= not_closed.state_time
group by news.id, news.state_time
order by id,  news.state_time
```

My test data (borrowed from Rob):

```
    create table mytable (id,state,state_time) 
    as 
    select 1, 'New', to_date('2009-03-03 00:03:31','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
    select 1, 'Closed', to_date('2009-03-04 04:15:27','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
    select 2, 'New', to_date('2010-05-22 14:38:49','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
    select 2, 'Open', to_date('2010-05-22 14:39:14','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
    select 2, 'Fixed', to_date('2010-05-22 17:15:27','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
    select 3, 'New', date '2009-01-01' from dual union all 
    select 3, 'Open', date '2009-01-02' from dual union all 
   select 3, 'Fixed', date '2009-01-03' from dual union all 
   select 3, 'Open', date '2009-01-04' from dual union all 
   select 3, 'Fixed', date '2009-01-05' from dual union all 
   select 3, 'Closed', date '2009-01-06' from dual
```

query results:

```
ID   NEW_IN            NEW_OUT           OPEN_IN           OPEN_OUT          CLOSE_IN CLOSE_OUT
1    3/3/2009 12:03:31 3/4/2009 4:15:27  3/4/2009 4:15:27   
2    5/22/2010 2:38:49 5/22/2010 2:39:14 5/22/2010 2:39:14 5/22/2010 5:15:27        
3    1/1/2009          1/2/2009          1/2/2009          1/3/2009          1/6/2009
```

I hope you can read the above, I'm having trouble formatting it.

Comment: You have a problem with your joins.  Everywhere that you're using "state <>", you'll get every row with a later time back.  For instance, using the poster's data, your first join will return 2 rows for id=2.  The first row will have new_out = 2010-05-22 14:39:14 (Open) and the second will have new_out = 2010-05-22 17:15:27 (Fixed).  If you're going to use this method, you need to make sure those inequality joins only result in one row being returned per ID.

Comment: Grouping by ID and news.state_time and using the min() aggregation function elimintates the extra rows. (I'm using "<=", "not "<>"). I'll post some test data and query results.

Comment: I don't think I understood exactly what Sarah wanted. The results of Rob's query do not exactly match my understanding of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you'd prefer to handle the situation where the same state is repeated more than once for an ID.  The following answer takes the easy route, assuming that you would want the first time the state was set and the last time the state was replaced.

```
select id, 
       min(case state when 'New' then state_time else null end) as new_in,
       max(case state when 'New' then out_state_time else null end) as new_out,
       min(case state when 'Open' then state_time else null end) as open_in,
       max(case state when 'Open' then out_state_time else null end) as open_out,
       min(case state when 'Fixed' then state_time else null end) as fixed_in,
       max(case state when 'Fixed' then out_state_time else null end) as fixed_out
from
    (select id, 
            state, 
            state_time, 
            lead(state_time) over (partition by id 
                                   order by state_time) as out_state_time
     from ...
    )
group by id
```

The `lead` analytic function gets the next row described by the partition/order statement, so that's the easiest way to find out when the state changed.  The middle query is a basic pivot query (transforming columns to rows).

Comment: Good point.  I updated my question to explain what I'm looking for.  IDs can definitely enter and exit a state multiple times, and there should be multiple rows to accommodate that as necessary.